# How I sum the amount on SQL Server table cell result vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Hi helpers Dear i think u dont understand . i have two column in sql table (id,Amount) i have some digit in my amount column , when i run the program then my amount should show in label1 , and when  i click on start timer button then 50 will sum at label1  like stopwatch but the amount should be sum like this format 0.0050

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
            Label6.Text += 1
            Dim n1 As Double
            Double.TryParse(Label6.Text, n1)
            Dim result As Double = n1
            Label1.Text = (result / 10000000).ToString(TextBox2.Text)

        End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id='" & "1" & "'"
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim table As New DataTable()
            adapter.Fill(table)
            If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then

                TextBox2.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
                cn.Close()
            End If


        End Sub
```

Comment: Try renaming the control variables so we can understand their purpose. We don't have enough to go on, trying to infer meaning from names like "TextBox1".

Comment: What is the purpose of using a timer?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you're asking. There's too much both in the text and the code that just makes no sense at all. But I do have some things you change to start with.

```vb
'Start by adding this to your form.
'Much better to keep this in an actual numeric type than a string.
Private timerTicks As Double = 0.0

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    timerTicks += 1.0
    'No idea what you were trying to do with TextBox2. It made no sense in that location.
    'If you used better names for the controls, we might be able to help more
    Label1.Text = (timerTicks / 10000000.0).ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Don't try to re-use the same connection object throughout your form!
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
          ' You're only using one field here: don't transfer to whole row over the network!
          cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT FieldName FROM Table1 WHERE id= @ID")

        'Match the exact type and length in the database here.
        ' Also, did you want to maybe use the timerTicks value?
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbtype.Integer).Value = 1

        cn.Open()
        Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        If result IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(result) Then
            TextBox2.Text = result.ToString()
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: See here for why not to re-use the same connection object: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query/398790#398790

Comment: Dear i think u dont understand . i have two column in sql table (id,Amount) i have some digit in my amount column , when i run the program then my amount should show in label1 , and when  i click on start timer button then 50 will sum at label1  like stopwatch but the amount should be sum like this format 0.0050